# Error:In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font Apear When update SDK tools

Tags: android

im reoppening a project in android studio, all com.android.anything and com.google.anything dependencies failed to resolve so update SDK tools to higher version and add maven`{url "https://maven.google.com" }` to repositories. error solved but new errors apeared :

```
Error:In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font
Error:In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontWeight
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processUniversalDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

my build.gradle dependencies section :

```
android
        {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {

        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "example id",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

        applicationId "com.example.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
}
ext.versionCodes = [armeabi:1, 'armeabi-v7a':3, x86:6]

import com.android.build.OutputFile
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // assign different version code for each output
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        int abiVersionCode = project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)) ?: 0
        output.versionCodeOverride = (abiVersionCode * 1000) + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1'
    compile 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.5.8, 3.99.99]'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
}
```

Comment: Can you post the part of the xml file where FontFamilyFont declare styleable is defined?

Comment: it's just define in R as below : 
`public static final int[] FontFamilyFont = {
            0x00000000, 0x7f0100e4, 0x7f0100e5, 0x7f0100e6
        };`

Comment: R.java is generated by gradle. The FontFamilyFont needs to be defined somewhere in the res/ directory of your project or the libraries you depend on.

Comment: It could be related to the issue in this library: https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/issues/116

Answer (score 0):

`buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'` requires google repository

In your main build.gradle, add:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        //...
    }
```

And have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)

Comment: it's not solving my problem